# How can I access/move handles of a dijit.slider or Dojox.RangeSlider on external input

Tags: exchange-server, slider, external, handle, dojo

Introduction: 
I have a dojox HorizontalRangeSlider UI component. On each side of this control I have a texbox displaying the value of the respective sliders.

Problem:
When I enter a new value in my textbox I can update the internal value of the RangeSlider but the handles do not respond to the change. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

An important point is to not set the properties directly but to use the attr(prop, val) function.